# jquery forms checking before making submit form active?

Tags: php, jquery, css, submit

i have this input file html form:

```
<input type="file" id="file" class="file customfile-input" name="file_upload">
```

and i have this submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Publish!" id="publish_button" name="submitPhoto" class="yellow_gradient big_button">
```

i wanted to do a jquery script that checkes to see if the input file field has been filled with the file before making the submit button active.
 thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#file").bind("change", function() {
    $("#publish_button").attr("disabled", this.value.length === 0);
});
```

This will re-enable the `#publish_button` right after the value inside the file input changes.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/hUDUC/1/

Comment: @getaway - be aware: with the submit button disabled initially people with javascript disabled (including screen readers that don't support javascript) will not be able to submit the form. See http://jsfiddle.net/hUDUC/2/ for a change which disable initially via javascript.

Comment: @StephenP: Great point! You could add your script before the `bind` call as well, just to keep the JS out of the markup.

Comment: yes, I usually have all javascript in a separate `.js` file, but there is a slight race allowing someone to click the button before it gets disabled even when using `.ready()`  I live with it, but others have raised objections to it before.